# Extract field A from an input list to be sorted on field B

Tags: python, list

Admittedly, not a very catchy title.

Given input:

```
input = [("baz", 3), ("bar", 2), ("foo", 1), ("qux", 4)]
```

What's the best way to get:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]
```

I could implement it, for example, as:

```
map(lambda x: x[0], sorted(input, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Iterating twice over the same data set seems wasteful. I wondered if there's a better way to tell the sorting function to pick the first field (instead of the whole record) while it's being sorted based on second field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided your first tuple elements are unique, 
you can process your `input` as `dict`. Still, this method 
works only if your `input` is a `dict` in the first place 
because otherwise you get an extra iteration in the `dict` constructor.

```
>>> input = dict([("baz", 3), ("bar", 2), ("foo", 1), ("qux", 4)])
>>> sorted(input, key=input.get)
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[i[0] for i in sorted(input, key=lambda x:x[1])]
```